# How can I Get the property by name from type and Set Propert value using reflection in C#

Tags: c#

I'm learning about C# reflection and ran into some road blocks along the way.  I have an example problem where I'm trying to perform the following:

1. Create new instance of Student - That I understand `Student sT = new Student()`
2. Get instance type -  That I understand: `var getType = sT.GetType();`
3. Get property FullName by name from type - How can I achieve this??
4. Set property value to "Some Name" using reflection.  How can I achieve this??

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //1. Create new instance of Stuedent

        Student sT = new Student();

        //2. Get instance type

        var getType = sT.GetType();

        var myStringProperties1 = getType.GetProperty("FullName",
                typeof(string));

        //3. Get property FullName by name from type  ????

        //4.  Set property value to "Some Name" using reflection        

    }
}

public class Student
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public int Class { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string GetCharacteristics()
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there; now just call SetValue on the property info:

```
//1. Create new instance of Student
Student student = new Student();

//2. Get instance type
var getType = student.GetType();

//3. Get property FullName by name from type
var fullNameProperty = getType.GetProperty("FullName",
        typeof(string));

//4.  Set property value to "Some Name" using reflection
fullNameProperty.SetValue(student, "Some Name");
```

Comment: Thank You for your help.  I was able to get the exercise to work.  I took your recommendation and was receiving the following error message. Assign GetProperty method return value to local vriable. Now sure what it meant, I decided to remove the typeof(string) and was able to successfully verify the problem in this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

you can also iterator through you properties

```
foreach (var pro in getType.GetProperties()/* get all your properties*/)
            {
               var type = pro.GetType();//Property type

                var propertyName= pro.Name;//Property name

                pro.SetValue(toObject,value);//set Property value
            }
```